# PresentationFontCache.exe using 99% cpu after starting a WPF app

Tags: wpf, windows

It happens on my father's machine that a service starts in the background, named PresentationFontCache.exe, as soon as my WPF app loads up. That process hogs 99% percent of the cpu constantly. As far as I know, PresentationFontCache.exe is a part of the .net framework 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The machine had .NET Framework 3.0 installed. Installing .NET Framework 3.5 removed the problem.